# How to get Days Remaining in Iteration using TFS REST API

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am currently using the `REST API version 2.0` and connecting to my TFS instance with `PowerShell`. I can get the following information:

Iteration ID
Iteration Name
Team Member
Team Member Capacity Per day using the example below

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/TeamSettings/Iterations/{iterationid}/capacities/{member}?api-version={version}
```

I can not figure out how to get the days remaining in the iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such direct api to get the days remaining in the iteration. You need to get the team setting for an iteration with api below, to get "startDate", "finishDate", "workingDays" in "teamSettings" and calculate the days remaining in the iteration:

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/TeamSettings/Iterations/{iterationId}?api-version={version}
```